# AWS services - ploting real time samples on graph

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have temperature sensor which I get samples from, and I want to present those samples as a function of a time with AWS services on a graph plot in real time.
What is the best service I can use in AWS?

Comment: [Amazon CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/)

Comment: Please clear the question up a bit. Function of time against Aws services in a plot? Or use your samples and host the soultion on Aws services?

Comment: sorry if I was unclear, I have temperature samples (Celsius degrees) from my temperature sensor in real time and I want to sent this data and store it in the cloud. I want to present this data by plotting a graph of the temperature samples as a function of a time. I am trying to find out what is the best AWS service I can use to do that. thank you!